# Widget settings disappear after refresh

Tags: widgets

I'm developing my own WP theme. But i have a problem with widgets.
So , when i drag and drop widget to sidebar area , it's settings don't appear. Appears only after refresh page. But at the other themes works correctly.

My codes :

Registering Widget areas :

```
  <?php
function themename_register_sidebars(){
    register_sidebar( 
        array(
            'name' => __('Main Sidebar', 'themename'),
            'id'   => 'main-sidebar', 
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s ch_widget widget_s1"><div class="ch_widget_container">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="ch_widget_title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span>'
        )
    );
    register_sidebar( 
        array(
            'name' => __('Sticky Sidebar', 'themename'),
            'id'   => 'sticky-sidebar',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s ch_widget widget_s1 "><div class="ch_widget_container">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="ch_widget_title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span>'
        )
    );
    register_sidebar( 
        array(
            'name' => __(' Footer 1', 'themename'),
            'id'   => 'footer-1',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s widget_section wg1"><div class = "widget_container auto_widget">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="widget_title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span>'
        )
    );
    register_sidebar( 
        array(
            'name' => __('Footer 2', 'themename'),
            'id'   => 'footer-2',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s widget_section wg2"><div class = "widget_container auto_widget">',
            'after_widget'  => '</div></div>',
            'before_title'  => '<span class="widget_title">',
            'after_title'   => '</span>'
        )
    );





}
add_action('widgets_init','themename_register_sidebars');

?>
```

Example sidebar :

```
      <section class = 'sidebar_container'>
 <?php
    if(is_active_sidebar( 'main-sidebar' )): 
        dynamic_sidebar('main-sidebar');
     endif ;
  ?>  
  </section>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify - does "at the other themes works correctly" mean you can add *the same widget* without any issues? Or are you just adding other widgets when you're using a different theme? Also, have you checked your console to see if there are any JS errors?

Comment: So , at the wordpress's own themes (twentyseventeen and others) widget settings appear without page refresh. But in my theme , widget settings (textboxes,buttons etc.) disappear.. I checked , there aren't any errors.

Comment: Where are the `div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s` variables coming from?

Comment: The code you posted above (`init` with `register_sidebars` and `is_active_sidebar`) is correct. There seems to be something other in your theme which will break this. If you have custom JS enqueued I would start by disabling this and see if it works again.  @WebElaine `div id="%1$s" class = "%2$s` this code comes from register_sidebar function and will create the right ID and class, take a look at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar).